# Invoke on static method throwing TargetException with HResult -2146232829

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, invoke, reflection.emit

The following call is resulting in a

```
TargetException
HResult = -2146232829
Message = Error in the application.
```

**CALL:**

```
builderType.CreateType();
// Exception on the following line:
int res1 = (int) builderType.GetMethod("Main", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(null, new Object [] { ((object) (new string [] { "Test" })), });
```

**CONTEXT:**

This call is placed after creation of the `TypeBuilder` and `MethodBuilder`as follows:

```
var domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
var name = new AssemblyName("HouseOfSynergy.PowerTools.ProcessRestarter");
var builderAssembly = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save, directory.FullName);
var builderModule = builderAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("HouseOfSynergy.PowerTools.ProcessRestarter", "HouseOfSynergy.PowerTools.ProcessRestarter.exe", Global.Instance.Debug);
var builderType = builderModule.DefineType("Program", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public);
var builderMethod = builderType.DefineMethod("Main", MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Private, typeof(int), new Type [] { typeof(string []) });
```

Please note that if I remove the `Invoke` call which is causing the error, the dynamic assembly loads and executes properly. The call to `Invoke` seems about right. Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

Comment: There are some special rules regarding the signature of a `main` method, that if violated could possibly cause this exception.  If you change your method name to `main2` does it work?

Comment: @PhilipPittle: It seems to work irrespective of the method name as long as I don't invoke it. @Gabi's answer is correct. Setting the access property to `RunAndSave` solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
var builderAssembly = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save, directory.FullName);
```

you only allow your assembly to be *saved*, not be *run*. See [AssemblyBuilderAccess documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilderaccess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In your case, you should use `AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave`.

Comment: Thank you. Starting with `Reflection.Emit` is causing a lot of `Doh!` moments.

Comment: Definitely. However, in some cases alternatives such as Expression Trees (which can also be compiled to an assembly if you want) may be easier.

Comment: I actually did look around for examples but did not come up with much in the way of compiling expression trees to assemblies. Please do post a link if you have one at hand.

Comment: See this question : http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1618682/linking-a-net-expression-tree-into-a-new-assembly
However, it makes only IL generation "easier", regardless of all the subtle errors you can run in when using AssemblyBuilder and friends :-)

Comment: Thank you. This is now enough direction to actually get somewhere.